# Rails where condition with nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

I found out that using where with symbol :my_id => nil and using old school one with ? is different. Could anyone explain me why?

```
MyTable.where("my_id = ? ", nil).first
SELECT `my_tables`.* FROM `my_tables` WHERE (my_id = NULL ) LIMIT 1
```

Does not get any data

```
MyTable.where(:my_id => nil).first
SELECT `my_tables`.* FROM `my_tables` WHERE (`my_tables`.`my_id` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
```

Get data which has my_id is null.

What is the best practise to use in rails?

I think I didn't make clear about my question.
In my rails application, request parameter is nil. 
Existing coding is MyTable.where(:my_id => params[:id]).first
In table, there are lots of records which have my_id is null.
Therefore, the first record from table is pick up without realizing. 
First of all, yes it is the problem with unclean data in table.

To solve this problem.
I find two solutions

Solution 1

```
if params[:id].present?
  MyTable.where(:my_id => params[:id]).first
end
```

Solution 2

```
MyTable.where("my_id = ? ", nil).first
```

As you know, if we put (if condition more and more), our application will get slower and it will not be functional programming.
When I try solution 2, I get surprised because I am expecting it should give same result.

Comment: Sorry, but your question doesn't make any sense to me anymore. Do you want to the records where `my_id` is `nil` or not??? The two solutions you mention above do two completely different things. My answer and that of leenasn explain why your "Solution 2" does not work. What do you want?

Comment: Yes you are right. There are completely 2 different things. I thought they are same. Solution 1 does not work for me because parameter could be nil and it will find records with NULL value. What I want is if parameter is nil, don't get anything. Thanks for your answer. It makes me clear after reading all answers. Thank you guys

Answer (score 60):

The correct SQL syntax is `my_id IS NULL`, so if you change your first snippet to the following it *will* work:

```
MyTable.where("my_id IS ?", nil).first
```

Both syntaxes are perfectly fine. It's up to your own preference. However, if it's a parameter and you don't know whether it will be `nil` or not, you'd better use:

```
MyTable.where(:my_id => parameter).first
```

Comment: are you sure? i get `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error ... near ''a'' at line 1` for query `SELECT 'a' IS 'a'` and proper result for query `SELECT 'a' = 'a'`

Comment: @keymone, yes I am sure. Note that the above only applies to `nil`. For strings/integers/booleans you *do* use `=`: `MyTable.where("name = ?", 'john').first`.

Comment: check out the meta_where (http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) gem...vastly powers up the way you can find things using the where clause in the Arel query methods...man, I'm always pushing this gem. you'd think I wrote it. I didn't, of course...

Answer (score 21):

In rails 4 you can specify the value as null using the new hash syntax.

```
MyTable.where(my_id: nil).first
```

Answer (score 11):

For DB for NULL the syntax should be

```
my_id IS NULL
```

So you can give it as:

```
MyTable.where("my_id is NULL ").first
```

Comment: Woof. I wish Rails had a Laravel-esque interface like `MyTable.whereIsNull(:my_id).first`

Comment: As mentioned in the below comment, you can use `MyTable.where(my_id: nil).first`

Comment: I hear you and it works just fine, but just hoping for an alternative interface someday.

Answer (score 1):

For any relational database the predicate `(my_id = NULL )` is *always* false, because NULL never equals anything - not even NULL.

A more complete explanation is here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166579/why-is-null-ignored-in-query-results/166586#166586.

ActiveRecord will cope with this very well, even when null is included in an array.

```
irb(main):029:0> Book.where(id: 1).to_sql
=> "SELECT ... WHERE \"books\".\"id\" = 1"
irb(main):030:0> Book.where(id: nil).to_sql
=> "SELECT ... WHERE \"books\".\"id\" IS NULL"
irb(main):031:0> Book.where(id: [1, nil]).to_sql
=> "SELECT ... WHERE (\"books\".\"id\" = 1 OR \"books\".\"id\" IS NULL)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's so called "rails magic" 
you can pass ranges

```
Client.where(:created_at => (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)
```

becomes

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.created_at BETWEEN '2008-12-21 00:00:00' 
                                                    AND '2008-12-22 00:00:00')
```

or if you pass a subset

```
Client.where(:orders_count => [1,3,5])
```

rails will do

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.orders_count IN (1,3,5))
```

[more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions)

Comment: What does this question have to do with ranges?

Comment: Nothing I think it's about hash conditions vs array conditions queries