# Rails function returns Nil but database entries are available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got this function:

```
def lessenActive
    Lesson.where("start_date < ? AND active = ?", DateTime.now,Nil).update_all(active: true)
end
```

it returns Nil .. But I can't understand why because in database are severall entries.

Using Rails 4.2

Comment: Try `active IS ?` instead of `active = ?`.

Comment: I know from experience that `where` seems to be picky about `nil`. Perhaps the answers to this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678723/rails-where-condition-with-nil-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Lesson.where("start_date < ? AND active IS NULL", DateTime.now).update_all(active: true)
```

SQL requires you to use IS instead of = to check for NULL, you could also use `"active IS ?", nil` as the comments suggest.

Comment: You can improve this answer greatly by explaining how your query differs from OP's query. Helping someone understand a concept is more useful than spoon feeding an answer.