# Why doesn't Rails 6 let me use `attr: nil` in a WHERE clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, select, ruby-on-rails-6, sql-null

In Rails 6 (with PostgreSQL), when I put `attr: nil` into a WHERE clause ActiveRecord puts `1=0` into the SQL, even when there are records in the database that are NULL for `attr`

I expected it to put `"attr" IS NULL` into the SQL as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65938514/2871922)

It only works as expected when I use an array like this: `attr: [nil]`, why is this?

so this is what I get in my Rails console:

```
irb(main):048:0> puts Output.where(value: nil).to_sql
SELECT "outputs".* FROM "outputs" WHERE 1=0

irb(main):049:0> puts Output.where(value: [nil]).to_sql
SELECT "outputs".* FROM "outputs" WHERE "outputs"."value" IS NULL
```

This is very frustrating because it means I have to remember to put variables into arrays when I use them in a where clause if there's any chance of the variable being nil (I always want nil to match NULL in my WHERE clauses, since NULL in the database is always returned to me as nil by ActiveRecord)

Rails version is <del>6.0.0.beta3</del> 6.1.4

here is my gemfile:

```
ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'

gem 'rails-reverse-proxy'

# create hashes from plucked data
gem 'pluck_all'

# Create DOCX files
gem 'caracal'

# Create Excel files
gem 'caxlsx'
# Read and edit Excel files
gem 'rubyXL'

# track changes in models
gem 'paper_trail'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.1', require: false

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
gem 'rack-cors'

# Google Cloud Storage with ActiveStorage
gem "google-cloud-storage", "~> 1.11", require: false

# Generate fake data
gem 'faker'
# easy factories for generating model instances for test and sandbox
gem 'factory_bot_rails'

# For gRPC
gem 'grpc'
gem 'grpc_for_rails'
gem 'googleapis-common-protos'
gem 'googleapis-common-protos-types'
gem 'gruf'

# To use Memcache as a cache store
gem 'dalli'
# Background processing, uses threads to handle many jobs at the same time in the same process
gem 'sidekiq'

# For converting HTML to PDF
gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 2.0.1'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.5.4'

# For getting image dimensions
gem 'fastimage'

# For scheduling jobs
gem 'sidekiq-scheduler'

# For consuming external APIs
gem 'httparty'
```

Comment: `where(attr: nil)` works as expected for me in Rails 6.1.4. Do you have any non-standard gems, concerns, ... in `Output`? Does this happen with all your models or just some?

Comment: What is the type of your `attr` column? Is it of type array?

Comment: @muistooshort it happens in all my models

Comment: @AnthonyTo in the example it's an integer, but the same thing happens on different column types

Comment: So what else is going on that's non-standard? Default scopes, concerns, gems, anything in `ApplicationRecord`? There are only two places where `1=0` shows up in ActiveRecord (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L890, https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L76) and they're both where you're explicitly asking for an empty result set.

Comment: Also, any particular reason you're using an old beta version of Rails? What happens if you switch to a proper release?

Comment: @muistooshort yes, I started wondering if it was to do with my beta version of Rails, which is why I belatedly added that info at the end of the question. Upgrading is on my todo list, and I'll comment here if it fixes it.

Comment: @muistooshort upgrading to Rails 6.1.4 hasn't solved this, so I suppose I should check my gems

Comment: Interesting. The only suspects I see would be `pluck_all` and `paper_trail` and I wouldn't think those had anything to do with the mysterious `1=0` (unless they're calling `none` somewhere). I suppose you could put breakpoints at those two places inside ActiveRecord and see what (if anything) is calling them.

Answer (score 1):

One of my colleagues finally discovered what was going on here. We had some code that was overwriting the behaviour of `where` in ActiveRecord and substituting `nil` for `[]`